# IF inside a map arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why does the if in this example, cause my react component not to compile.

How would one put a if like this in the map function then?

```
{this.props.medication.map((object, i) => (
  if(object.med_type){
    <div>
      <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-6">{object.item.description}</div>
      <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-6">{(object.med_assigneddate !== '' && object.med_assigneddate !== null) ? object.med_assigneddate : 'N/A'}</div>
    </div>
  }
))}
```

Comment: because `object.med_type` is falsy?

Comment: You probably want to actually `return` that expression, instead of doing nothing with it.

Comment: Try `object && object.med_type && <div...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrow functions can have, on the right-hand side of the `=>` symbol either:

- A block
- A statement (which gets an implicit `return` ahead of it)

If you want an if statement with its own block, you need to write the function body as a block and explicitly include the return statement.

```
(object, i) => {
  if (object.med_type) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-6">{object.item.description}</div>
        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-6">{(object.med_assigneddate !== '' && object.med_assigneddate !== null) ? object.med_assigneddate : 'N/A'}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be better `filter` first and then use the `map`. You have to `return` something from `map` scope. For sample:

```
{this.props.medication.filter(object => (object.med_type)).map((object, i) => (
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-6">{object.item.description}</div>
        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-6">{(object.med_assigneddate !== '' && object.med_assigneddate !== null) ? object.med_assigneddate : 'N/A'}</div>
      </div>);
))}
```